# ScalaPb annotations on sealed trait

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, scalapb

I am trying to put an annotation on top of a generated sealed trait using scalaPb this way:

```
message SealedTrait {
 option (scalapb.message).annotations ="@zio.json.jsonDiscriminator("strategy")';

oneof sealed_value {
  A a = 1;
  B b = 2;
}}
```

unfortunately the annotation is generated not on the trait but on SealedTraitMessage instead.
Is there a way to add annotations on the sealed trait?

Comment: Are you trying to turn PB messages into JSONs for some purpose? Because most of the time it is much easier to create separate models for each distinct purpose and use annotations/implicits/extending traits for each for them in isolation. This way you don't fight against the current but go with the flow. But if you really have to I think the only options that I see in the docs is this https://scalapb.github.io/docs/customizations#custom-base-traits-for-sealed-oneofs - create your own `trait` (perhaps make it extends the default one) and annotate it.

Comment: Tried already, sealed trait extends the one you put there and it does not work since the trait is not sealed

Comment: Then I would suggest to, if possible, create a separate case class/ADT for your JSONs. It is quite clear (with annotations used for configurations) that ZIO JSON is intended to be used with data types you have complete control over and can modify them arbitrarily.  Use Scala PB classes only for protobufs, use separate JSON types only for JSON serialization, convert between them by hand or with data mapping library like [Chimney](https://chimney.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [Ducktape](https://github.com/arainko/ducktape/) or [Scala Automapper](https://github.com/bfil/scala-automapper).